# What causes 'Broken pipe' errors in a Django application on GKE, and how can I prevent them?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

I have deployed a Django application on a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster, and it has been functioning well. However, recently I encountered a "Broken pipe" error with the message "Broken pipe from ('35.191.194.192', 57892)" in my application logs. Notably, I did not release any updates during this time, and there were no indications of a broken error in the load balancer logs. and , the error disappeared after some days, even though no new updates were deployed. I would like to understand the root cause behind this issue and learn how to prevent it from occurring in the future.

I did not take any specific action to address the issue since it resolved itself after some days. However, I expected to understand the cause of the "Broken pipe" error and find ways to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.